# (MAC) PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Web3\Web3' not found

Tags: php, ethereum, web3php

I'm new to PHP, and I was trying to run 
`$exampleBase.php` from web3.php on mac

but it keeps showing error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Web3\Web3' not found in /Users/hsnl/Desktop/code/back-end-php/web3.php/examples/exampleBase.php:7
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 {main}
>   thrown in /Users/hsnl/Desktop/code/back-end-php/web3.php/examples/exampleBase.php on line 4

`$exampleBase.php` file is like this

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
use Web3\Web3;
$web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545/');
```

any idea why or how should I fix this?

Comment: Do you have `Web3\Web3` defined in your `composer.json` file? Did you run `composer install`?

Comment: i use the `$composer.json` file in web3.php on [github](https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php/blob/master/composer.json)
but yet I dont see a specific definition of Web3\Web3. 
what should I add in the file? @AlexHowansky

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run sc0Vu, please try to follow this steps:
https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php#local-php-cli-installed

> Clone the repo and install packages.

```
git clone https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php.git && cd web3.php && composer install
```

This means:

- clone github project,
- go to cloned directory,
- run composer install
  (will download and create all necessary files with classes)

> Run test script.

`vendor/bin/phpunit`